# Nonautonomous wave equation of memory type

Tags: partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators, hyperbolic-equations

I want to apply the semigroup approach of nonautonomous evolution equation for the following wave equation
$$u'' - \Delta u + \int\limits_0^t {g(t-s)} \Delta u(s)ds = 0$$
This problem can be written under the standard form of Cauchy problem
$$U' = A(t)U$$
where$$
A(t)=\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\ 
\Delta -\int_{0}^{t}g(t-s)\Delta ds & 0%
\end{array}%
\right) 
$$
 It is obvious that we can't apply the classical semigroups approach because the operator $A$ in this case depends on $t$. I tried to find some references which talk about these things but I didn't secceed. I want from you some advice or halp. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this kind of problem with $\int\limits_0^t {g(t-s)} \Delta u(s)ds=(g*\Delta u)(t)$ instead of  $\int\limits_0^t {g(s)} \Delta u(s)ds$.

For this kind of convolution term, we have [this](https://content.iospress.com/articles/asymptotic-analysis/asy772) paper where the authors study the more general case $$u''(t) + A u(t) -(g*Au)(t) = 0$$
with $A$ being a self adjoint positive definite operator. The idea is to take the solution $r$ of
$$r(t)-(g*r)(t)=g(t)$$
and introduce the new variable
$$v(t)=u(t)-(g*u)(t).$$

From this you obtain an equivalent problem, which also have a convolution term. Removing this term, you obtain an equation which can be studied via classical semigroup theory. This enables you to study the complete equation, via fixed-point method.

[Here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ade/1355867334) there is another paper, where the same idea is applied to Timoshenko beams.

(The said papers have free versions available on the internet; just ask google.)

Comment: Thank you sir, I have modified the post. thank you again.